# "se lo lleva la corriente" (el pronombre de objeto indirecto)

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, modismos

El el dicho "camarón que se duerme se lo lleva la corriente". Mi pregunta es, por qué dice "se lo lleva" en vez de "lo lleva?" "Se lo lleva" a mi parece superfluo. Entiendo que no es, pero no entiendo por qué.

Comment: "Llevarse" significa "tomar algo consigo" ("take something away"). Está explicado en el duplicado que he propuesto, pero háznoslo saber si ese duplicado no responde a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @wimi. Ahora entiendo la diferencia entre llevar y llevarse, pero todavía no entiendo por qué dice "se lo" y no sólo "se lleva". A mi parece que "se" y "lo" aquí hace referencia al camarón, y eso me parece superfluo. Entiendo que no es, pero no entiendo el porqué.

Comment: Lo refiere al camarón.  La corriente se lleva el camarón.

Comment: "lo" hace referencia al camarón. "se" es un pronombre reflexivo, que hace referencia a la corriente.

Comment: ¡Ah! Finalmente pienso que yo entiendo. "Lo" es el camarón, y "se lleva" significa "it carries." Es un poco más fácil para mí imaginar, por un momento, que dice "Lo, se lleva," o "it, the current carries." Muchas gracias a Karlomanio y Wimi.